# Horizontal scrollbar blocking one-line code on Stackoverflow

Tags: user-experience

When there's only one long line of code (just long enough to require a scrollbar), the scroll bar will totally block the code (please move your mouse over to see)

```
When there's only one line of code, the scroll bar will totally block the code like this
```

and I cannot find a feedback/suggestion page on Stackoverflow...so posting as a question here

Comment: I don't see a scrollbar. Also, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326473/one-line-codeblock-scrollbars-wont-disappear

Comment: thanks! I was looking for that question